# I would enjoy it, but I've already seen it

Tags: grammaticality

CONTEXT:

John has asked Samantha out, and they are going to the movies. John tells Samantha the name of the movie they are about to watch. Samantha has already seen that movie, and she doesn't want to watch it again, but she decides that she'll still watch it out of politeness and in order to keep John company. John says to her: "I'm sure you'll enjoy the movie!". She relplies to him with one of the sentences below.

SENTENCES:

1. I **would enjoy** it, but I've already seen it. Anyway, let's go watch it.
2. I **would enjoy** it, but I already know what it's about. Anyway, let's go watch it.

QUESTION:

Does "would enjoy" work in the above two sentences?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, the mood is incorrect and both sentences reach the wrong ending. I suggest either "I would enjoy it, but I've already seen it. Let's see something else." Or "I have seen it, but I would enjoy watching it again. Let's go"!

Comment: "I would have enjoyed it" seems more natural as you're saying something that was true in the past (if I had gone with you last week, before I saw it) but not now. In contrast, something like "I would beat you at tennis, but I've broken my arm" is OK because you're talking about something happening in the present (playing tennis). Being a native speaker, I'm not exactly sure of the grammatical rule to invoke here.

Comment: @Stuart F: (A) I **would beat** you at tennis, but I've broken my arm. = I **would beat** you at tennis, if my arm weren't broken. But it is broken, so I won't beat you. (B) I **would enjoy** watching the movie, but I've already seen it. = I **would enjoy** watching the movie if I didn't know what it was about. But I know what it is about, so I won't enjoy watching it. ___ I think the tennis example is logically equivalent to movie example. In both cases, the speaker is talking about something that is not likely to happen in the future. Does my reasoning make sense to you? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Yes, it's my sort of film ... but I'm afraid I've already seen it. I _did_ enjoy it."